# Create table with postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table with PostgreSQL but I have a problem.
I have the following request :

[image]

I can't access it when I try to make a request in my `.php` file.

I think there is a problem with the double quotes : `"tListeDeroulante"`. With the other tables, I don't have them. So I tried to remove them by modify the `CREATE` request but it doesn't work.
And when I delete the table and I create it again, I have the same error. Maybe I forgot something when I create the table.

Help please !

Comment: In short: do not use double quotes when creating tables. That makes the identifiers case-sensitive. For details see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but I don't choose to add the double quotes. That's what I want, how can I avoid to add the double quotes when I create the table ?

Comment: When the table name contains capital letters, you MUST add double quotes, if you don't want to add double quotes you MUST remove the capital letters and use only lower case.

Comment: @Houari That's it ! Thank you very much !!

Comment: I don't understand you. If you don't want the double quotes, then don't type them. Or did you _generate_ that code somehow through some tool instead of typing manually? That's the curse of GUI tools, they just do things you don't tell them to.